# Save a Dynamics CRM 2011 form inside a Silverlight browser component

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a Silverlight 5 application with a webBrowser component in it. Inside the Silverlight Webbrowser I show a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 form. I want to save the form entity when the user clicks a button in the Silverlight application. How can I do that?

I tried the invokeScript method like this:

```
webBrowser.InvokeScript("saveForm");
```

It cannot find the method saveForm, although it is there in a JScript file. This JScript file is loaded in the form that is shown in the Silverlight Browser component.

the saveForm javascript method looks pretty simple:

```
function saveForm() {
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementById('crmContentPanel').ownerDocument.frames[0].Xrm.Page.data.entity.save()" });
```

put this to the Silverlight application. Hope it helps someone.